# Existentially quantified types Could not deduce in the typeclass context

Tags: haskell, typeclass, existential-type

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification, DeriveDataTypeable #-}
import Data.Typeable;

data EnumBox = forall s. (Enum s, Show s) => EB s
           deriving Typeable

instance Show EnumBox where
  show (EB s) = "EB " ++ show s
```

This works. 
But if I want to add a instance of Class Enum for EnumBox likes:

```
instance Enum EnumBox where
  succ (EB s) = succ s
```

It fails with the message:

```
Could not deduce (s ~ EnumBox)
from the context (Enum s, Show s)
  bound by a pattern with constructor
             EB :: forall s. (Enum s, Show s) => s -> EnumBox,
           in an equation for `succ'
  at typeclass.hs:11:9-12
  `s' is a rigid type variable bound by
      a pattern with constructor
        EB :: forall s. (Enum s, Show s) => s -> EnumBox,
      in an equation for `succ'
      at typeclass.hs:11:9
In the first argument of `succ', namely `s'
In the expression: succ s
In an equation for `succ': succ (EB s) = succ s
```

Why the first show can be deduced but the second succ cannot?

Comment: Seems like you forgot to apply `EB` to `succ s`.

Comment: You are right. I miss the wrapper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only problem is that `succ` has the type

```
succ :: Enum a => a -> a
```

So you need

```
succ (EB s) = EB . succ $ s
```

Just boxing it up again.

Also you'll probably want

```
instance Enum EnumBox where
    toEnum = EB
    fromEnum (EB i) = fromEnum i
```

As this is the minimum definition of completeness, since

```
succ = toEnum . succ . fromEnum
```

Comment: There is only one exception. In the toEnum function, it lost the type wrapped by EnumBox. In this case, toEnum . fromEnum (EB 'a') /= EB 'a'